# Uploading pdf to server from android

Tags: android, pdf, upload

I am trying to upload an pdf file from android mobile to server. I tried with image it works fine with image. but when trying to upload pdf file it gives me error.

I am using eclipse API 18

I tried this:
On list Item click it opens an file explorer

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    int sub=subid.get(position);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Integer.toString(sub),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

}
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String filepath;
        if (resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
            filepath=getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(UploadAssignment.this, data.getData());
            System.out.println("File "+filepath);

        }


        //new Upload(UploadAssignment.this, namepath,Integer.toString(prn),sname,Integer.toString(sub)).execute();
    //    } 
    }


 public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        String result = null;

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
                context, 
          contentUri, proj, null, null, null);        
        Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

        if(cursor != null){
         int column_index = 
           cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
         cursor.moveToFirst();
         result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        return result;  
  }
```

here getRealPathFromURI_API11to18() method returns me null.
i dont know why it is giving me null value.

Comment: This contant ensure that you browse image files only. User MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA MediaStore.Files to browse pdfs

Comment: @Honza Musil What should we use to upload pdf. files.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing set type "application/pdf" to the intent and after getting URI you are trying to get RealPath using  **MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA** which is used to get path for images only. It will not allow to read path from URI for your pdf file. You could try something as below :

```
 try{

         /*Used if you want to upload file object*/
        File mFile = new File(new URI(mNewPath));

        /*Used if you want to read absolute path of that specific file*/
        String mPath = mFile.getAbsolutePath();

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i have tired this it gives me error:java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 42: /document/3565-3161:OnlineStatementOfMarks (1).pdf
I have also printed uri path that show me on logcat : content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/3565-3161%3AOnlineStatementOfMarks%20(1).pdf

Comment: 03-20 16:27:58.754: I/System.out(24744): Excp java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute: %2Fdocument%2F3565-3161%3AOnlineStatementOfMarks+%281%29.pdf

Comment: I am not able to get .replaceAll("%20"," "); on my uri

Comment: I tried this String may=path.getPath().toString().replaceAll("%20"," "); and i got error 03-20 16:38:42.784: I/System.out(26818): Excp java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 42: /document/3565-3161:OnlineStatementOfMarks (1).pdf

Comment: Hi, It seems that your file name and path contains number of special characters and space. So try to apply trim() on that string

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this link [upload file](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/)